# How do I use PHP code stored in a database and echoed in a new page?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner in PHP, so I need a little help.

I have stored some PHP code in a MySQL database (in a table), and now I'm trying to echo in another PHP page (`<?PHP echo $result['code'];?>`) after making a successful connection with the database and selecting the right table where I stored the code in the `code` column. But it is not working.

If I store HTML or JavaScript or any code in the database and try to echo, the content is displayed as it was programmed, as you can see in this image:

[image: So here is the image of view-sourcecode page where I'm trying to show that HTML or HTML CSS works perfectly, but in the case of PHP it shows the PHP in red colour and it does not work].

But it doesn't work with PHP. How can I fix it?

Comment: PHP has to be pre-processed, thus the name.  If you have php code and you simply echo it, it will not be processed.  You may want to look into the [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function

Comment: @mtr.web please help.me...that how can I do that...means using the code which I have stored in the database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to have to do some guessing, and show a very simple example, but something like the following should work.

1. Add a `code_type` column to your table with values of html, **php**, etc.
2. Make sure that any php code stored in the database has been tested and returns some output (without using `<?php` tags). For example:

   ```
   $var1 = 100;
   $var2 = 10;
   $var3 = 1;

   echo "<h1> The equation of ($var1*$var2+$var3) equals</h1>";
   echo "<p>".($var1*$var2+$var3)."</p>";
   ```
3. Use the `code_type` in your data-output script to either evaluate the PHP code or just echo it in all other cases:

   ```
   <?php
   if ($result['code_type'] == 'php') {
       eval($result['code']);
   } else {
       echo $result['code'];
   }
   ?>
   ```

I cannot say that I have ever used this, so I can't guarantee anything, but hopefully points you in the right direction.

**Important:**

It is worth noting that this is not considered good practice, as noted multiple times in the [PHP Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). The manual itself notes it in several places, but the first comment is on-key:

> If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong
>   question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP

... You are probably a lot better off parsing the php code before you save it to the database, then you won't have to worry about any of this!

Comment: I want to ask another thing suppose if the code contains both HTML and php or css or php..than how it will work..because it is working only if the code is in php

Comment: That's why you'd have to add a column to your table that tells you the code-type. There are other ways, like a true/false is-php column or a comment in all php values to search for